# How to copy and duplicate row from a table in Oracle SQLdeveloper?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In an table **myTable** in Oracle. I got many rows and I simply wanna create a duplicate of just one row **nROW**? Is there a way to to it graphically through SQLDeveloper GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the row in SQL Developer, right click, and select "Duplicate Row"

I am using SQL Developer version 17.2.0.188. I believe this has been available for some time in older versions.